Is there a general guideline to conjure up a mathematical expression to convey a system?
Pardon my naivety. I'm new to academic paper authorship. I would like to understand, is there a general guideline on how to think & express concepts in terms of mathematical expression.
Often times (in my personal intellectual capacity) when I see papers with lot of mathematical constructs I feel intimidated and wonder how the authors have constructed the expression. But when I understand the paper, little bit deeper, I come to know the underlying concept is just common sense which could have expressed with just literature. So I wonder sometimes these Mathematical expressions are sometimes used as an intellectual garnish to uplift the novelty of the paper. Though I'm sold on this practise, I still don't understand how do I make use of it. I did some research on symbol meaning (such as ∑ for aggregation, ∆ for change in value etc), but is there any generic guideline / method that can be used to convert a concrete system / concept to a mathematical expression?

‘Mathematical expressions are sometimes used as an intellectual garnish to uplift the novelty of the paper.’ I’m interested to see a few examples of this. Please share.

You misunderstand the purpose of using such mathematical expressions rather than "just literature". Such expressions are both compact and precise, whereas literature is often at least a bit ambiguous. Words in a given language seldom have an absolutely precise meaning and when used in combination, various interpretations are possible.
That ambiguity (potential) is the reason that there is no reliable automatic system for converting ordinary language into mathematical symbols and expressions. For things that have existed for a long time it may be possible to do something with, say, an LLM, but not for newly created ideas. Language can give an "idea" of what is going on, and provide metaphors for understanding, but precision is required for the accurate transmission of ideas; hence equations and such.
What is needed is experience and insight, which is gained from long practice and deep thinking. You seem to admit this yourself when you write of deeper understanding. Once you have the concept precisely internalized, it seems natural and the language can follow as long as peers accept the "translation".

The craft of converting vaguer qualitative notions into precise ones is precisely the history of modern science. We can assume that quite certainly smarter members of society, especially in "leisurly" positions of priests and astronomers might have had a pretty good understanding of what was going on in the skies (there is famously a cave painting about 30,000 years old, possibly predating organized statehood, showing the phases of the moon), but making it precise requires language.
So, calendars were probably the first step to achieve that, and as tools were refined (think Euclid's geometry), suddenly new insights were possible. And that continued with Archimedes, Galilei, Newton and so on.
In short: science is the craft of giving precision to vague or unexpressed insights into the nature of the world. Maybe AI will make that easier, but for now that should give you an impression for the magnitude of the problem you are talking about.
